# result of while loop showing differently

Tags: php, mysqli

In the first page of my site the user suppose to see some categories, under each category there are some sub-categories. I am fetching these categories and sub-categoires from database. There are two tables in the database called "category" and "subcategory" and i have tried to merge these two tables. The ouput should be something like this

[image: the expected ouput]

but i am getting this ouput

[image: the ouput i am getting]

here is my code

```
<?php 

    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $db="doc";

    $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

    $show=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.category_name, b.subcat_name, b.cat_name
        FROM category a, subcategory b
        WHERE a.category_name = b.cat_name");

?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <div class="col-lg-3 sidebar">  
            <?php
        while($showsub = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show)) { ?>

                <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-cube"></i><a href="category.php?id=<?php echo $showsub['id']; ?>"><?php echo $showsub['category_name']; ?></a>
                        <ul style="list-style-type:circle">
                            <li><?php echo $showsub['subcat_name']; ?></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?php
            }; ?>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am stuck here for last 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db="doc";

$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-3 sidebar">  

        <?php
        $cat = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT id, category_name FROM category");
        while($rowCat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat)) 
        { 
        $catName = $rowCat['category_name'];
        ?>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
                    <a href="category.php?id=<?php echo $rowCat['id']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $rowCat['category_name']; ?>
                    </a>

                <?php
                $subCat = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE cat_name='$catName'");
                while($rowSubCat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subCat))
                {?>
                <ul style="list-style-type:circle">
                    <li><?php echo $rowSubCat['subcat_name']; ?></li>
                </ul>
                <?php }?>

                </li>
            </ul>
        <?php
        }?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Nana Partykar

Comment: Glad to help Ashiqur.

Answer (score 1):

You should format the array first accordingly -

```
$categories= $subcats= array();
while($showsub = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show)) { 
    $categories[]= $showsub['category_name']; // array of categories
    $subcats[$showsub['category_name']][]= $showsub['subcat_name']; // array of sub categories with category as indexes
}; ?>
```

Then the HTML -

```
foreach($categories as $cat) { // Loop through the categories array
?>
<ul>
      <li><i class="fa fa-cube"></i><a href="category.php?id=<?php echo $showsub['id']; ?>"><?php echo $cat; ?></a>
          <?php foreach($subcats[$cat] as $subcat) {?> // loop through the subcategories depending on categories
          <ul style="list-style-type:circle">
               <li><?php echo $subcat; ?></li>
          </ul>
          <?php } ?>
      </li>
</ul>
<?php
}
```

Comment: can you expalin the code a little bit
and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just two general advices: Learn a templating system to be able to split presentation (html) and Logics (php) and look into using prepared statements for MySQL - that will make your life a lot easier a little bit down along the road

What you get is exactly what would be expected from the code you have shown. You ask for each subcategory with its category. You have two different ways of solving this:
Either - as Sougata said - make two different tables and join then accordingly. But it is also possible to make the  two-level list from one table. Then you need to make sure that the categories and subcategories comes in an order that makes sense:

```
$show=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.category_name, b.subcat_name, b.cat_name
    FROM category a, subcategory b
    WHERE a.category_name = b.cat_name
    order by category_name, subcat_name");
```

If you just add on "order by" to Your sql-query, Your output should look like

- Category 1

  - Subcat 1
- Category 1

  - Subcat 3
- Category 1

  - Subcat 5
- Category 2

  - Subcat 2
- Category 2

  - Subcat 4

The next step will be to add some logics to supress repeating categories:

```
<ul>
<?php
 $oldcat="";
 $started=0;
 while($showsub = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show)) { 
    $cat=$showsub['category_name'];
    $subcat=$showsub['subcat_name'];
    if ($oldcat != $cat){
        if($started){print("</ul>");}
        print("<li>$cat</li><ul>\n");
    }
    print("<li>$subcat</li>")
 }
 print("</ul></ul>\n");
?>
```

This is not a direct replacement of your code, but I hope you get the idea. Read it as a php-heavy pseudo code...

and again, please do yourself a favour and start using a templating system..